# Ansible - Access inventory alias

Tags: ansible

Having an inventory file like:

```
[my_hosts]
my_host ansible_ssh_host=123.123.123.123
my_host2 ansible_ssh_host=234.234.234.234
```

I want to gather some debug information in my templates.

- How do I acces the alias variable in a playbook/template?
  I.e.:

  ```
  debug: msg=Myhost is {{ ansible_host_alias }} 
  # Myhost is my_host
  # Myhost is myhost2
  ```

I tried to gather facts using `ansible -m setup my_host` . The variables `ansible_hostname` , `HOSTNAME` and `HOST` contain the machine's hostname, i.e. `echo $HOSTNAME` which differs from my ansible alias.

Comment: Be aware that `ansible_ssh_host` has been deprecated in favour of `ansible_host` in v2.0. ([docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups)). 

Likewise `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_port` to become `ansible_user` and `ansible_port`. These shorter variables are ignored, without warning, in older versions of Ansible.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The variable I was searching for is a built in feature: `inventory_hostname`

Ansible documentation about `inventory_hostname` and `inventory_hostname_short` is found from chapter [Magic Variables, and How To Access Information About Other Hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).

Original question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/Oa5YXjHecIw

Comment: Awesome find... I missed that one.

Comment: Correct first link please!

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `inventory_hostname` special variable.

Documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

Alternatively,

You can just simply use `{{ ansible_ssh_host }}` For example:

Inventory:

```
[my_hosts]
my_host ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 my_host_alias=my_host
```

Playbook:

```
---
- name: My Good playbook
  user: ubuntu
  hosts: all

  tasks:
    - name: My message
      debug: msg="Myhost is {{ ansible_ssh_host }}"

    - name: My message bogus
      debug: msg="My host alias is {{ my_host_alias }}"
```

Execution:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory play.yml

PLAY [My Good playbook] *******************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [my_host]

TASK: [My message] ************************************************************
ok: [my_host] => {
    "msg": "Myhost is 127.0.0.1"
}

TASK: [My message bogus] ******************************************************
ok: [my_host] => {
    "msg": "My host alias is my_host"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
my_host                    : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the alias (so the output should be 'my_host') and not the IP Address. The background is: I am trying to integrate the existing infrastructure with ansible and I only got the IP addresses. In some tasks I am gathering information about the servers (writing stats into templates) and therefore I would like to put the alias into template

Comment: Thanks, the problem about this solution is its redundancy: I am defining the alias twice (That is why I wanted to know whether there is a builtin ansible variable for alias, but there seems to be no such thing)